Identify group level row in matrix visual using measure
I have a matrix in visual in PowerBI desktop in which I am trying to identify the group level row.
If my data contained car makes and drivers:
Car, Driver
Mercedes, Peter
Mercedes, Matt
Mercedes, Cliffe
Mercedes, Frank
BMW, Lucy
BMW, Warren
BMW, Martin

If my visual based on this now groups the drivers by car make.
Car, Driver
+Mercedes
*Peter
*Matt
*Cliffe
*Frank

Now in the grouped row that currently shows Mercedes I could of course show a max or min aggregate based on the other columns.
Is there a way tho to identify the grouped row in DAX and print out a specific value, i.e. a text?
Desired output
Car, Driver
+Mercedes, GROUPLEVEL TEXT
*Peter
*Matt
*Cliffe
*Frank

